# How can i use POST method for Google Translate

Tags: php, zend-framework, curl

How can i use POST method for Google Translate. I dont want to use JS for some reason, Need to do it with PHP. The following does not works.

```
  public static function googleTranslatePost($text = "What are you looking at", $destLang='fr', $srcLang = 'en')
  {

    $http_response = ''; 
    $ch = curl_init('http://translate.google.com/translate_t');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'hl=en&ie=UTF8&text=-->this+is+a+test<--&langpair=en%7Car');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $http_response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $http_response; 

  }
```

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: I get no response nor errors from php.

Comment: WORKING NOW - https://gist.github.com/728228

Comment: Does google block POST or GET method if its from PHP or etc ?

Comment: From browser this works but same thing from php does not works now. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=how%20are%20you%20&@&langpair=en|en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey man, I've found this class on google. Let me know if that is helpful:

http://code.google.com/p/gtranslate-api-php/

Comment: In GET method: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=hello&langpair=en|fr   Gives-->{"responseData": {"translatedText":"bonjour"}, "responseDetails": null, "responseStatus": 200}   --> But mine POST does nothing

Comment: ABOVE code is half in my case, i just need a simple curl function as post towards my destination. WORKS ex: https://gist.github.com/728228

Comment: I evaluate myself and then mark 100% if its really solved. The link didnt solved it yet. Yesterday worked today GET or POST none working.